# Javascript: Remove node from object

Tags: javascript, object

I have object:

```
var obj = [{"id":1,"name":"Mr.A"},{"id":2,"name":"Mr.B"},{"id":3,"name":"Mr.C"}]
```

How can I remove node when know `id` (Ex: id = 2) with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var obj = [{"id":1,"name":"Mr.A"},{"id":2,"name":"Mr.B"},{"id":3,"name":"Mr.C"}];

obj = obj.filter(node => node.id != 2);

console.log(obj);
```

I used an arrow function. If you need to support old browsers, replace it with a standard function.

Comment: It should work. If it isn't, you did not show us all relevant code. We won't be able to help you. What is not working? Are you getting an error message? Is you array a real array or an array-like object?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript treats that as a set of objects stored in an array. To access any particular object you would use obj[/*index, 0-2 for your example*/]. to add/remove objects refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.

I hope this helps.